# LSTM Sequential Val Loss > Train Loss on Same Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have a fairly simple LSTM Sequential Model defined as follows

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(neurons, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, n_input_steps, n_features), stateful=True, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dense(n_output_steps))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='SGD', metrics=['MeanAbsolutePercentageError','RootMeanSquaredError','MeanAbsoluteError'])
```

I have trained this model close to 1000 epochs with a successful decrease in loss as expected, as well as a corresponding decrease in the other metrics as well.

Now when I run a simple test for 1 epoch of training and validation on this trained model using the **training data** as both train and validation, I get this issue:

```
94705/94705 [==============================] - 534s 6ms/step - loss: 0.8181 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 2.9242 - root_mean_squared_error: 212.3811 - mean_absolute_error: 43.8881
val_loss: 7.0263 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 27.3711 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 217.5867 - val_mean_absolute_error: 66.8557
```

This makes no sense because there is an order of magnitude in loss and MAE (I use a custom loss function that's a modification of MAE but for this question we can just look at MAE). There is no way that on the **SAME dataset**, a training MAE would be 3% and validation MAE would be 27%

You can verify my model.fit code here

```
def fit_lstm(X, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, neurons):
for i in range(nb_epoch):
    lstm_model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=False, callbacks=[cp_callback,csv_logger], validation_data=(X, y))
    lstm_model.reset_states()
    print("Epoch: " + str(i) + " of: " + str(nb_epoch))
return lstm_model
```

and then

```
lstm_model = fit_lstm(X_train, y_train, batch_size, epochs, neurons)
```

Of course I am having the same issue with using model.predict() on the same X_train dataset. The errors are a 10x higher than the training (exactly in line with the model.evaluate result)

I understand the basic concept that model.train updates weights at each batch and at the end of the training epoch, so it's expected there is some variance between training results and evaluate (that goes through the whole dataset with fixed weights), but it does not make sense that it would be this different

I did find this issue reported in the Keras Github

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977

However, the solutions there either had to do with

1. removing Dropout or Batch Normalization, which I don't have)
2. K.set_learning_phase(0), which doesn't make sense because it's default behavior for evaluation so it's set to 0 anyway. Also, setting to (1) which would seem to force it to behave like model.fit also does not do anything
3. Loading the model differently (via checkpoint, then weights) does not work. This would be a major bug in Keras (not being able to load model correctly) so that can't be it anyway. Loading a model allows it to continue training fine, but doesn't fix in any way the model.predict/evaluate issue
4. 

Appreciate the help

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the exact same issue with an almost the same LSTM regression model that does not employ regularization.